# ADO.Net with ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I want to learn the complete ADO.Net, what are the topics that are there in ADO.Net.

Is this the only way to connect to databases in ASP.Net for SQL Server.

I have searched in Google, I got some of the topics but I couldn't get all the topics.
So friends if any one please let me know about Complete ADO.Net and this must be used for Employee level (i.e as an Developer not for beginners).

I know database Connections from ASP.Net, working with Data bound objects only.

What more I need to go through in ADO.Net

Please let me know as it helps me a lot any to many Freshers.

Thanks in Advance
Ganesh

Comment: Go and buy a book for complete ADO.net or download E-books available

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492350/recommend-a-good-ado-net-book

Answer (score 0):

You can start learning directly from the Microsoft ASP.NET website here:

[data-access](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access)